# Problems with defining modules using AMD in Mocha

Tags: mocha.js, amd

While writing tests I got bug `TypeError: $.extend is not a function` on toastr plugin that we are using. It seems that jQuery is not picked up properly, even tho is working normally in browser.

In our main mock file we imported jQuery and bind it to global windows object and it's accessible across whole application (but toastr plugin), even while testing in mocha:

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
import $ from 'jquery';
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiImmutable from 'chai-immutable';
import React from 'react';

const doc = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
const win = doc.defaultView;

global.document = doc;
global.window = win;
global.expect = chai.expect;
global.$ = $(win);
global.jquery = $(win);
global.jQuery = $(win);

Object.keys(window).forEach((key) => {
  if (!(key in global)) {
    global[key] = window[key];
  }
});

chai.use(chaiImmutable);
```

So while taking closer look at toastr I noticed this:

```
; (function (define) {
    define(['jquery'], function ($) {

    // this function is called on inizialization
    function getOptions() {
        return $.extend({}, getDefaults(), toastr.options);
    }
```

It takes `jquery` from node_modules directly and then defines object `$` in function scope, that means that it's ignoring `window.$` (which is working normally even in here).

Therefore logging `$` will return function, and logging $.anyMethodFromjQuery (`$.extend`) will return undefined.

In the end I tried logging $.prototype, in the browser it will return me jQuery object while in mocha it returns empty object `{}`

So in the end it define didn't created prototype in mocha environment and I cannot add one line of code `$ = window.$;` in plugin, since no one should edit a plugin + we are using npm.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: How is `toastr` loaded?

Comment: With npm, in application I just use `import toastr from 'toastr'`;

Answer (score 0):

You're running into trouble because you are loading code that should be loaded by JSDom outside of it. While it is *possible* in some cases to load code in Node and then pass it to the window that JSDom creates, that's a brittle approach, as you've discovered. Whenever I use JSDom for things other than write-and-toss cases, I load every script that would normally be loaded by a browser through JSDom. This avoids running into the issue you ran into. Here's a proof-of-concept based on the code you've shown in the question. You'll see that `toastr.getContainer()` runs fine, because Toastr has been loaded by JSDom. If you try to use the same code with an `import toastr from "toastr"` you'll get the same problem you ran into.

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
import $ from 'jquery';
import path from "path";

const doc = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>', {
    features: {
        FetchExternalResources: ["script"],
        ProcessExternalResources: ["script"]
    }
});

const win = doc.defaultView;

global.document = doc;
global.window = win;
global.$ = $(win);
global.jquery = $(win);
global.jQuery = $(win);

window.addEventListener("error", function () {
    console.log("ERROR");
});

const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = path.join(__dirname, "./node_modules/toastr/toastr.js");
document.head.appendChild(script);

// The load will necessarily be asynchronous, so we have to wait for it.
script.addEventListener("load", function () {
    console.log("LOADED");
    console.log(window.toastr);

    // We do this here so that `toastr` is also picked up.
    Object.keys(window).forEach((key) => {
        if (!(key in global)) {
            global[key] = window[key];
        }
    });

    toastr.getContainer();
});
```

Note that the code hung when I tried calling `toastr.info(...)`. I took a look at the code of Toastr but it is not clear to me what causes the problem. There are features of browsers that JSDom is unable to emulate. It is possible that Toastr is dependent on such features. In the past, I've sometimes had to switch test suites away from JSDom due to its limitations.

Comment: This looks good, the only problem is that script wont load so  `script.addEventListener("load"` never fires, therefore I still have the same problem. I'm now trying to find effective way of inserting toastr with jsdom

Comment: Whenever I post code of this sort, I test it before posting. So yes, it does work. I've tested it. Of course, if you did not `npm install toastr` beforehand, it won't load.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it could be the problem with `path.join('../../node_modules/toastr/toastr.js');` I'm checking that out now

Comment: The problem was it's absolute path, not relative, but it showed the same error. I even change the project itself and load toastr as a script in .html file and removed `import toastr from toastr`. Again it works normally in browser, and not in mocha. No matter what I do, I think that `define(['jquery'], function ($) {` replace usage of global jquery object and that cannot be avoided.